# Publish extension based on React js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Is there any option will not get extension reject on publish in google web store if i'll use react js code?
Coz if i use minified js code , i cant success extension publish.
And js source map didnt help at all . 
Did some one rich this ?

Comment: Use the full, non-minified react.js.

Comment: What is the reason the extension is being rejected? I've used the minified version of react in my chrome extension without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restrictions for that (if you do not violating React license).